# android studio (0.8.2) layout preview : NullPointerException at com.android.internal.app.WindowDecorActionBar.setHasEmbeddedTabs

Tags: android, intellij-idea, android-studio, android-5.0-lollipop

I have recently updated the android studio to 0.8.2 . Now when I created the new project I am not able to see the preview of the layout . Here is the log :

```
> Rendering Problems java.lang.NullPointerException   at
> com.android.internal.app.WindowDecorActionBar.setHasEmbeddedTabs(WindowDecorActionBar.java:265)
>   at
> com.android.internal.app.WindowDecorActionBar.init(WindowDecorActionBar.java:217)
>   at
> com.android.internal.app.WindowDecorActionBar.<init>(WindowDecorActionBar.java:182)
>   at
> com.android.layoutlib.bridge.bars.ActionBarLayout.<init>(ActionBarLayout.java:98)
>   at
> com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.createActionBar(RenderSessionImpl.java:1620)
>   at
> com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.inflate(RenderSessionImpl.java:352)
>   at
> com.android.layoutlib.bridge.Bridge.createSession(Bridge.java:329)
>   at
> com.android.ide.common.rendering.LayoutLibrary.createSession(LayoutLibrary.java:332)
>   at
> com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runReadAction  
> ... (ApplicationImpl.java:932)   at
> com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl$2.run   ...
> (ProgressManagerImpl.java:178)   at
> com.intellij.openapi.progress.ProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManager.java:209)
>   at
> com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:212)
>   at
> com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.runProcess(ProgressManagerImpl.java:171)
>   at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.execute   ...
> (MergingUpdateQueue.java:320)   at
> com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.execute(MergingUpdateQueue.java:310)
>   at
> com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue$2.run(MergingUpdateQueue.java:254)
>   at
> com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.flush(MergingUpdateQueue.java:269)
>   at
> com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.flush(MergingUpdateQueue.java:227)
>   at
> com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.run(MergingUpdateQueue.java:217)
>   at
> com.intellij.util.concurrency.QueueProcessor.runSafely(QueueProcessor.java:238)
>   at com.intellij.util.Alarm$Request$1.run(Alarm.java:327)
```

Comment: Same problem here. If you've found an answer, please let me know!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its working now ... what all I did was

1. Start the `sdk manager` . Install the default selected packages . eg. Tools,Extras
2. after installation has finished I restart the android-studio .

3 . Boom.....it worked ....